# stopService(Intent) Method Not Stopping The Service

Tags: android, service

I called the stopService() method from the calling class when the calling activity exits, and the service does not stop. It keeps on running in the background and can thus be a hastle to the end user. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Code:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView listView;
static int cnt1=0;
static int bob=1;
RelativeLayout background2;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);



background2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
int num = 0;
final ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
Intent calledActivity = getIntent();
final List pe = calledActivity.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Caller1");

String[] s = new String[pe.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < pe.size(); i++) {
    s[i] = (String) pe.get(i);
}

final ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pe);
theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
final int cnt = 1;
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
mIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("Caller2", (ArrayList<String>) pe);
mIntent.putExtra("intCall",bob);
startService( mIntent);



theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String s1 = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        pe.remove(s1);
        if (pe.size() == 0) {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MyService.class));

            Intent goback;
            goback = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(goback);
        }
        ((BaseAdapter) theAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
});
}
```

MY SERVICE CLASS:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

return null;}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! Blocker Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(final Intent intent, int startId) {
int i=0;

    Timer t = new Timer();

    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                                  List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);


                                  ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = tasks.get(0);
                                  String activityOnTop=ar.topActivity.getClassName();
                                  Intent lockIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, LockScreen.class);
                                  lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                  ComponentName componentInfo = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
                                  if(!componentInfo.getPackageName().equals("com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate"))
                                  {

                                        startActivity(lockIntent);
                                      Log.v("iwashere", "-- ACTIVITY --");
                                  }
                              }


                          },
            0,

            1000);

    Toast.makeText(this, "My Blocker Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}


}
```

Comment: First, are you sure that your `stopService()` call is being called? Second, how have you determined that your service is not being destroyed? If it is because your leaked thread is running, that's because you leaked the thread. You need to stop your `Timer` in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: The onDestroy method has a toast, which does apear, even after I added timer.cancel(); it doesn't work

Comment: "The onDestroy method has a toast, which does apear" -- then your service is being destroyed. Please explain **completely and precisely** why you think that "stopService(Intent) Method Not Stopping The Service".

Comment: That is what is puzzling me

Answer (score 1):

[Docs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fjava%2Futil%2FTimer.html&ei=DK7PVJmiINjZatP9goAG&usg=AFQjCNFOmQV7mTFhVw9N9MnENAeP3Sf1mA&sig2=OvydEg_-SvnqwPJphBEsPg&bvm=bv.85076809,d.d2s) say:

> Each timer has one thread on which tasks are executed sequentially.

So I see you have a thread in your service.If you created a thread,you can not stop it until it does it's task,unless it has a task that involves a loop.In this situation,in loop condition,you can check if this thread received stop message(cancel) or not?And if is received,stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Note to self:

Bro, put       System.exit(0)     in     onDestroy()     , after      timer.cancel()      &     timer.purge()